# No certificates are available in developer portal

Tags: ios-provisioning

[image]

I have enabled push notification service for app. I am getting the following error when I try to create provisional profile for app distribution:

```
No Certificates are available.
Click "Create Certificate." to create a Certificate. You need a Certificate to configure a Provisioning Profile.
```

I have no idea about this error. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Before to create a provisional profile, you need create a certificate for you app.

Steps:

1. Create App ID
2. Create Certificate (Development o Production).
3. Create Provisional Profile

Comment: You have created you certificates?

Comment: Yes.I created certificated for APNs

Comment: The certificate should not be created correctly.
Have a problem to create CSR file?